# How to get an ASP.Net webapp to send data to a .Net desktop application and back

Tags: asp.net, .net, desktop-application

I am building a web application, where a function is needed where i could make the web app send a specific stream of data to the desktop application, which is running on the web server where the website is also running on.
In example: you push a button, a certain code (probably an integer/string code) gets sent to the desktop app which then does something.

Why it's needed/wanted: we currently use this desktop application to quickly launch specific gameservers, without having to fiddle around with a million different shortcuts to each server, for each different configuration.
Now we'd like to have a web application to work as a "middle man" so certain people could start gameservers without having to connect to the server through RDP.

Extra info: the desktop app is currently written in VB.Net, but rewriting it in C#.Net shouldn't be a big problem, if it's needed.

Does anyone of you guys know of any good tutorials or techniques to do this, or have a better solution for my needs?

Comment: Sounds like a job for a web service that the desktop application can interface with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about setting up some code in your Web app to write data to a DB. You could then have your desktop app poll the database using a backgroundworker. If it finds new records then it can continue processing.

Comment: That's actually not a bad idea, Thanks!